# Using .forceignore to ignore listViews for certain objects

Tags: salesforcedx, .forceignore

I am trying to make it so we can create list views in scratch orgs that will not be pulled into our source when developing. I have created a `.forceignore` file in the root directory.

[image]

My `.forceignore` file looks like

```
# Ignore List Views
avsight/main/default/objects/Product2/listViews
avsight/main/default/objects/Account/listViews
```

But when I create a new listView for the Product2 object and do a `force:source:pull` the listView is not ignored and it gets added to the source. Does anyone see anything wrong with how I am doing it or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This had me stumped for a while too... and with some trial and error I was able to get this working (for the scenario of ignoring all list views for Contact).

```
Contact.listView
```

The .forceignore actually has 2 sets of syntax, 1 for ignoring when pushing, and another for ignoring when pulling. This is kinda mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_exclude_source.htm), but it's not overly obvious, and a **key** thing is trying to get the right case to use as it's case sensitive (and not aligned to the *Type* that gets listed in a *status* command.

Comment: *.listView also works, thank you.

Comment: Surelt *.listView works as a wildcard, and hence doesn't answer the OP's question, which was about specific listViews.

Answer (score 0):

With some help from [this closed GitHub issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1471) in the [forcedotcom repository](https://github.com/forcedotcom), the below should also work for what you need:

- `**/Product2/listViews/**`
- `**/Account/listViews/**`